# how to save libsvm model in matlab

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm using libsvm in matlab, and it seems there no existing method to save the model formed from svmtrain. Instead, the functions provided forces me to retrain everytime. Just saving the svmtrain model variable in a .mat does not work. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about SVM, unlike NN is that training is fast and in some cases can be even done online.  I have a multiclass SVM and I save the training vectors, classes and the kernel parameters into a txt file.